# Max depth of tree in a maze

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, complexity-theory, maze

Suppose I have a N*N maze, for the worst case(I can use either Breath first search or Depth first search). What is the maximum depth of my search tree?

My understanding is it will be 2*(N-1) in this case.

Comment: The absolute worst case would be the total number of blank grid-cells in your maze array, which could be O(N*N)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog but that is not the worst depth but space right?

Comment: It is also the worst depth. Imagine that the graph is completely connected; both the start and finish points are at dead ends. Depending on the situation, the recursion *could* traverse every cell without backtracking until it reaches the end. There is nothing to limit the size of a maze graph in this case, other than the grid it is embedded in, so the worst case depth is O(N * N) (with the constant < 1)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what if backtracking technique is implemented?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Recursive algorithms automatically backtrack when each call is finished.